# How to seed/insert specific value after a specific value changes SQL/Hive

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, seed, bda

My objective is to make a table in Hive wherein for every new value of a column, say name, it will seed a word.

any code sample that can do this?

expected result:

| name | transaction date | transaction code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Karen | 01012021 | ABC |
| Karen | 01022021 | DEF |
| Karen | 01032021 | ABC |
| Karen | 01042021 | GHI |
| name | transaction_date | transaction_code |
| Gilbert | 01012021 | ABC |
| Gilbert | 01022021 | DEF |
| Gilbert | 01032021 | ABC |
| Gilbert | 01042021 | GHI |
| name | transaction_date | transaction_code |
| Sherwin | 01012021 | ABC |
| Sherwin | 01022021 | DEF |
| Sherwin | 01032021 | ABC |
| Sherwin | 01042021 | GHI |

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  It is unclear what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can find distinct name (create a view or table)
2. Loop through each value
   2a) As you are looping make a insert "name" | transation_Date | code

Not sure if you can do alone in Hive but with a combination of Python/Spark/Scala you can do this. Hope it helps in some ways.